# Json does not write the returned object to the console

Tags: json, ajax, rest, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have this piece of code that consumes a restful API using ajax. I am just trying to write on the console the returned data from the API, to my surprise it does not show any data, what's to be corrected?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "http://localhost:8800/dialects",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data){
           console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

When I query the endpoint directly from the browser it returned the object's endpoint: `http://localhost:8800/dialects`. Sample of returned objects:

```
[{"glottocode":"zyud1238","names":"Zyuzdin","isocodes":"","macroarea":"Eurasia"},{"glottocode":"zwal1238","names":"Zwall","isocodes":"","macroarea":"Africa"},{"glottocode":"zuwa1238","names":"Zuwadza","isocodes":"","macroarea":"Papunesia"},{"glottocode":"zuti1239","names":"Zutiua","isocodes":"","macroarea":"South America"},]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using content-type attribute in ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8800/dialects",
    type: "get",
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
       console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. it's not pulling the data as well. I don't know what could be the cause. The same line of code I wrote and it worked for another project I did, so I'm confused what's missing. Any ideas?

Comment: can you elaborate little bit about Server API and middleware you are using.